# How to change active buttons in a dynamically generated bootstrap pagination?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, pagination

I have a quiz system, where you can ask questions on different pages. Page 1 shows a picture of a tree, page 2 of something else... and the user can write questions for the specific page.

Now I try to implement a simple pagination (I have seen the example for the play-computer-base example, but I dont think I will need that), but cant change the pages.

This is the pagination so far:

[image: Pagination]

When the user clicks on `2`, it should switch to it.

Therefore I implemented a navigation-element:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        @for(index <- 1 to 10){
            <li class="@("active".when(index == currentPage))"><a href="@routes.Application.index()">@index <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is within the `"active".when(index == currentPage)` part, this is not correct at the moment. As this is a scala template, is there a way to change the active state of the current button?

Answer (score 1):

Just try an `if` condition for the currentPage inside the `for` loop. This should probably work.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        @for(page <- 1 to 10){
            <!-- Assuming you know the value of variable currentPage -->
            @if(page == currentPage) {
                <!-- Current page -->
                <li class="active"><a href="#">@{page}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            } else {
                <!-- Anchor tag to that page -->
                <li><a href="route_to_that_page_number">@{page}</a></li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```